# Foundation z-index for nested element

Tags: css, zurb-foundation, z-index, positioning

so I built my layout to the exact specifications but when I try to push the `.feat` section up (`position: absolute; margin-top: -60px;`) over the header element I run into z-index issues.

I've read many posts on setting the header element to `position: relative;` but that's not doing it.

[a visual for you: the image should be over the white background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XT2qN.png)

Here's [my codePen](https://codepen.io/luukee/pen/jQpxYG?editors=1100) with the exact setup.

I would really love to get this, thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: I wouldn't use this concept in this layout. If you want, I can teach you how to build your own layouts much more logically stronger, clearer and easier. It can seem hard, but this would be most effective way.
the first thing in your code that brings problem - is .grid-y.grid-frame height and overflow:hidden - this won't give the picture to overlap the whole wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this layout without using the absolute positioning for your different sections. Foundation offers [**XY Grid**](https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/xy-grid.html) which can be used as demonstrated in the code examples/CodePen link below:

**HTML**

```html
<div class="grid-container fluid">
  <div class="grid-x header">
    <div class="cell auto">
      <h1>Coming to the Stage</h1>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="grid-x grid-margin-x">
    <div class="cell medium-8">
      <div class="grid-y h-100">
        <div class="cell shrink">
          <div class="grid-x grid-padding-x synopsis">
            <div class="cell medium-4">
              <p>Synopsis</p>
            </div>
            <div class="cell medium-8">
              <p>Comedy powerhouse Jim Gaffigan has made a career out of finding the extraordinary </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="cell medium-shrink">
          <div class="grid-x grid-padding-x metainfo">
            <div class="cell medium-4">
              <p>Credits</p>
            </div>
            <div class="cell medium-8">
              <div class="grid-x grid-padding-x">
                <div class="cell medium-6">
                  <p>Talent</p>
                </div>
                <div class="cell medium-6">
                  <p>Jim Gaffigan</p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="grid-x grid-padding-x">
                <div class="cell medium-6">
                  <p>Directors</p>
                </div>
                <div class="cell medium-6">
                  <p>Aaron Feldman</p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="grid-x grid-padding-x">
                <div class="cell medium-6">
                  <p>Producters</p>
                </div>
                <div class="cell medium-6">
                  <p>Jim Gaffigans</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell medium-4">
      <div class="grid-x grid-margin-x">
        <div class="cell medium-10 feat">
          <img src="http://www.comedydynamicsstaging.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/unnamed.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="cell medium-2 pagination">
          1 2 3
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="grid-container fluid">
  <div class="grid-x">
    <div class="cell medium-12 extra-meta">
      Extra meta
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: green;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

.header {
  height: 285px;
  background: grey;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.h-100 {
  height: 100%;
}

.feat img {
  margin-top: -60px;
}

.synopsis {
  background: red;
  height: 100%;
}

.pagination {
  background: blue;
}

.metainfo {
  background: orange;
  height: 100%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
  .metainfo {
    margin-bottom: 60px;
  }
}

.extra-meta {
  background: pink;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

**CodePen example**

Link to **[CodePen example here](https://codepen.io/ahdigital/pen/vQVOEO)**.